# Как настроить синхронизацию потоков C#?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно останавливать все потоки кроме одного, который удовлетворяет условию  в определенный момент времени и затем как условие не выполняется снова запускать все потоки используя синхронизацию потоков.

В приложение по примеру № 3 добавить вертикальную область. Внутри
области может находиться только один шарик, другие шарики ожидают,
пока область не освободится. Применить синхронизацию потоков.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        class Ball
        {
            static object locker = new object();
            public int x, y; // координаты
            int dx, dy; //приращение координат-определяет скорость
            int w, h; //ширина высота шарика
            public bool live = true; // признак жизни
            public delegate void DlTp();// Объявление типа (делегат) и
                                        //создание пока что пустой ссылки для организации в последующем
                                        // с помощью ее вызова функции Invalidate()для главного потока
            public DlTp dl;
            public Thread thr; //Создание ссылки на потоковый объект
                               // потоковая функция
            public void FnThr()
            {
                    while (live)
                    { //здесь отражемся от границ области
                        if (x < 0 || x > 200) dx = -dx;
                        if (y < 0 || y > 200) dy = -dy;
                        //здесь пересчитываем координаты
                        x += dx;
                        y += dy;
                        Thread.Sleep(30);//спим
                        dl(); //вызываем с помощью делегата Invalidate()
                    }
                w = h = 0; //схлопываем шарик
                dl(); //вызываем с помощью делегата Invalidate()
            }
            //функция рисования шарика
            public void DrawBall(Graphics dc)
            {
                dc.DrawEllipse(Pens.Magenta, x, y, w, h);
            }
            //конструктор класса
            public Ball(int xn, int yn, int wn, int hn, int dxn, int dyn)
            {
                x = xn; y = yn; w = wn; h = hn; dx = dxn; dy = dyn;//инициализируем
                thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FnThr)); //создаем потоковый объект
                live = true; //устанавливаем признак жизни
                thr.Start(); //запускаем поток
            }
        }
        Ball[] bl = new Ball[10];//массив пустых ссылок типа Ball
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int j = 0; j < bl.Length; j++)
            {
                //создаем потоковые объекты
                bl[j] = new Ball(j, j * 10, 10, 10, j + 1, j + 1);
                //подписываемся на событие
                bl[j].dl += new Ball.DlTp(Invalidate);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bl.Length; j++)
            {
                bl[j].DrawBall(e.Graphics);//рисуем
               
                if(bl[j].x > 200)
                {
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < bl.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (bl[i] != bl[j])
                        {
                            lock (typeof(Ball)) bl[i].FnThr();
                            Console.WriteLine(bl[j].thr.ThreadState);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bl.Length; j++)
            {
                bl[j].live = false;// Уничтожаем потоки
            }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bl.Length; j++)
            {
                bl[j].live = false;//уничтожаем потоки
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что у Вас не работает?

Comment: у меня все потоки останавливаются разом, а идея в том, что когда шар пересекает определенную границу, то, все кроме того шара который пересек границу должны остановиться, т.е. потоки, которые обрабатывают остальные шары должны остановиться на время пока первый шар, не выйдет из границы
я не могу понять как это реализовать

Comment: Это учебное задание на потоки? Или для себя? От этого зависит ответ.

Comment: @aepot это учебное задание

Comment: Еще раз дополнил ответ, наверное последний вариант - как раз то что вам нужно по заданию.

Comment: @aepot огромное спасибо, вариант с ManualResetEventSlim идеально подошел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте вложенные типы, это будет вас только путать и стимулировать написание грязного кода. Располагайте классы рядом друг с другом, а не внутри.

Вот так

```
public class Ball
{
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
}
```

В идеале эти классы нужно расположить в разных C# файлах.

Решение простое.

```cs
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bl.Length; j++)
    {
        if (bl[j].live) // если неживой, игнорируем его
        {
            if(bl[j].x > 200) // если пересек
                bl[j].live = false; // убиваем
            else
                bl[j].DrawBall(e.Graphics); // иначе рисуем
        }
    }
}
```

Вместо пары x,y используйте структуру `Point`

```cs
public class Ball
{
    public Point Position;
}
```

Избегайте сокращений, код из непонятно почему так названных переменных (`FnThr` => `RunLoop`) очень сложно читать.

Вот, смотрите разницу:

```cs
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < balls.Length; j++)
    {
        if (balls[j].IsLive)
        {
            if(balls[j].Position.X > 200)
                balls[j].IsLive = false;
            else
                balls[j].Draw(e.Graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

Не экономьте буквы, от этого код быстрее работать не будет.

Что касается самого условия задачи, заведите еще одно поле, чтобы шарики можно было не только убивать но и на паузу ставить.

```cs
public bool IsActive;

public void RunLoop()
{
    while (IsLive)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 200) dx = -dx;
        if (y < 0 || y > 200) dy = -dy;
        
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30); // спим
        } while (!IsActive); // пока деактивирован
        OnPositionChanged();
    }
    w = h = 0;
    OnPositionChanged();
}
```

Или даже так

```cs
private ManualResetEventSlim _activeLock = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);

public void RunLoop()
{
    while (IsLive)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 200) dx = -dx;
        if (y < 0 || y > 200) dy = -dy;
        
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        Thread.Sleep(30); // спим
        _activeLock.Wait();
        OnPositionChanged();
    }
    w = h = 0;
    OnPositionChanged();
}

public void Deactivate()
{
    _activeLock.Reset();
}

public void Activate()
{
    _activeLock.Set();
}
```

Comment: @ПашаВасильев но вообще мне кажется, это задача на примитивы синхронизации, быть может вам нужен мьютекс или ManualResetEventSlim например. Заведите статический в классе Ball, как только шарик входит в область, делайте ему Reset, и снова Set как выйдет. И пусть каждый шарик так себя ведет. Возможно мой ответ кривоват, но мне было сложно читать ваш код. В общем нужно знать контекст, чтобы предложить правильное решение.